# Creating a Ruby Class on the fly without eval

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, eval

I need to create a Ruby class on the fly, i.e. dynamically, that derives from `ActiveRecord::Base`. I use `eval` for the time being:

```
eval %Q{
  class ::#{klass} < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "#{table_name}"
  end
}
```

Is there an equivalent, and at least equally concise way to do this without using `eval`?

Answer (score 15):

You can use the [Class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html) class, of which classes are instances.  Confused yet? ;)

```
cls = Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) do
  self.table_name = table_name
end

cls.new
```

Comment: This is it, thanks. I know that classes are objects too; but I did not know that it is possible to give the base-class as an argument and in particular about the block (in hindsight, I should have guessed).

Answer (score 4):

Of course, there is :)

```
class Foo
  class << self
    attr_accessor :table_name
  end
end

Bar = Class.new(Foo) do
  self.table_name = 'bars'
end

Bar.table_name # => "bars"
```